# CSS background image gets out of scale

Tags: css, background-image

I want to put an image as a background for a site. So i found some info on the net. But it gets out of scale. The bottom part. How do i make the image fit the screen without getting out of bounds?

```
body,
html {
    min-height:100%; 
}

body {
    background-image:url("hanted.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;

}
```

Comment: you may try `background-size:cover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

background-size requires two values, so it should be `background-size: 100% 100%;` (width and height)

Edit: For the sake of the general correctness of my answer, it doesn't actually *require* two values to be correct syntax, but if you only have one height is set to auto. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: but setting background-size: 100% 100% will distort the image if the container ratio doesn't match ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS3 prefixes. Try something like this:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```